# Is it possible to execute a korn shell script passing an array as parameters?

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, parameters, paramarray

I'm trying to execute a korn shell script using an array, but I would like to see if this is possible, I don't want to do is the follow example:

```
Script="/home/Myscript.sh"
. ${Script} "Value1" "Value2" "Value3"
```

Would be better if I can do something like:

```
Array[0]="Value1"
Array[1]="Value2"
Array[2]="Value3"
. ${Script} "${Array}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible!

You just have to put something like:

```
. ${Script} "${array[@]}"
```

If your array have more than 1 value, all of those will be received. :)